# In $\Delta ABC$ $\angle BAC = 40^\circ, AB = 10$ and $AC = 6$. Points $D$ and $E$ lie on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In $\Delta ABC$, $\angle BAC = 40^\circ, AB = 10$ and $AC = 6$. Points $D$ and $E$ lie on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. What is the minimum possible value of $BE + DE + CD?$

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I have already seen the solution in the Art of Problem Solving Website, because this is one of the $2014$ AMC $12$A Problems.
Check the solutions here :- https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2014_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_20

The problem, however, is that all the solutions use Law of Cosines as Trigonometry, and I prefer using simple geometry techniques to solve this problem.

So is it possible to solve this without Trigonometry? Thank You.

Comment: Based on solution 3, we need to find the opposite side to $120^\circ$ with the remaining sides being $6$ and $10$. I believe there are elementary ways to find this side with using the Cosine Law, exploiting the $120^\circ$.

Comment: Rereading the solutions, I see that they are all actually using the same method. For a $120^\circ$ angle, there are indeed some elementary methods to find the remaining side without using the cosine law (and *proves* that $c^2 = a^2+ab+b^2$). One is found in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132579/how-to-find-the-remaining-segment-of-this-triangle-without-the-law-of-cosines using Pythagoreas theorem, the one summarized in https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/CosLawFor60and120.shtml uses a clever construction with regular polygons, and there is also a proof with similar triangles.

Comment: I was busy with work and doing this in between :) clearly missed your link in the question and the essence of your question! So deleted my answer. Yes I think principle of reflection is the best way to approach this question as some solutions suggest. You can avoid cosine law if you have to and use Pythagoras instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In this construction we have $|AB_1|=|AB|=10$, $|AC_1|=|AC|=6$,
$|ED_1|=|ED|$, $|D_1C_1|=|DC|$.

Since $\angle C_1GA=90^\circ$ and
$\angle GAC_1=180^\circ-3\cdot40^\circ=60^\circ$,
$\triangle C_1GA$ is half of the equilateral triangle
with the altitude $C_1G$, hence
\begin{align} 
|AG|&=\tfrac12\,|AC_1|=3
,\\
|C_1G|&=\sqrt{|AG|^2+|AC_1|^2}=\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\,|AC_1|=3\sqrt3
,\\
|BG|&=|AG|+|AB|=13
,\\
|BC_1|&=|BE|+|ED_1|+|D_1C_1|
\\
&=|BE|+|ED|+|DC|
\\
&=\sqrt{|BG|^2+|C_1G|^2}=\sqrt{196}=14
.
\end{align}